# Special character encoding is lost when string is passed to function

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

```
string = "Magic Cookie® Extra"
print string
```

Will give the output:

```
"Magic Cookie® Extra"
```

However, if I pass the string into this function, which combines it with another string:

```
def label_print(label, string):
    print label + ": " + string

label_print("Product name", string)
```

Will give the output:

```
"Product name: Magic Cookie?? Extra"
```

Why is this and how do I prevent it?

Does the concatenation with the first string reset the encoding so that the `®` character becomes `??`.

I have tried editing the function so that the local variable `label` is `label.encode("utf-8")` but that doesn't help.

I also have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the very top of my Python file.

Comment: Is that Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @AaronDigulla Python 2.7. Sorry, will update the tags.

Comment: Where are you running that code? It's giving me a `UnicodeDecodeError` in the Jupyter notebook (that I expected) and I can't even paste ® in the python console.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really reproduce this on my Linux and Windows systems, where the `string.encode("utf-8")` line actually generates a `UnicodeDecodeError` exception. The text displays fine on Linux, although Windows generates gibberish in both cases.

Comment: I guess you forgot to mention some import from `__future__`.

Comment: @Goyo The actual source of the string is from `Selenium WebDriver` and is scraped from a webpage. There might be something there causing this but not sure yet.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please show real code and if possible a [mcve].

Comment: @Winterflags My comment was about `string.encode("utf-8")` that you removed from the question.

Comment: Is your original string actually a python 2 `str` or unicode?

Comment: @Goyo It's text contents taken from a webpage source code. I found a "solution" (if you can call it that). If I do `string = string.decode("utf-8")` before passing it to the `label_print` function, it will print the symbol correctly. I'm not sure yet why that fixes things however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run your code, I get

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

when I try to call `string.encode('UTF-8')`, so there is something else at work here.

Generally speaking, you must not mix strings which are UTF-8 encoded with ones that are not. Either everything is encoded or nothing. No mixing.

One way to solve these problems in Python 2 is to use unicode strings:

```
string = u"Magic Cookie® Extra"
print repr(string)
print repr('a ' + string + ' b')
```

which prints:

```
u'Magic Cookie\xae Extra'
u'a Magic Cookie\xae Extra b'
```

As you can see, even though the strings in the concatenation aren't unicode strings, Pyhton "upgrades" them. This will work pretty well ... unless you have UTF-8 encoded byte strings somewhere ...

Note: The `?` means that someone has installed an output converter for `sys.stdout` which converts unknown/unprintable characters into `?`. Search all your sources for `sys.stdout` to find out why this happens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply – Sorry but I'm having trouble creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example. I have now tried to recreate the chain of code I thought was essential for this error, but I can't reproduce it. There is something in my original program (around 600 lines) that interacts here unexpectedly, so I might have to revisit this question.

Answer (score 2):

As you said in comments that the string was scraped from a web page, here is a possible explaination of what happens. UTF8 encodes characters above 127 as multi byte characters. For example the `®` character has code `0xae` and is encoded in utf8 as `'\xc2\xae'`.

So your string is actually `'Magic Cookie\xc2\xae Extra'` and when concatenated leads to `'Product name: Magic Cookie\xc2\xae Extra'`.

As @AaronDigulla explained, the two special characters are then translated as `?` giving the result.

An consistant way to obtain it is to use the `encode` method with `'replace'` error handler:

```
>>>> print 'Product name: Magic Cookie\xc2\xae Extra'.decode('ascii', 'replace').encode('ascii', replace')
Product name: Magic Cookie?? Extra
```

But until you say exactly what you do and what you want, I cannot tell you how to fix...

Comment: Thanks Serge! I will investigate this further and apply the "Answered question" accordingly if I find something in the direction you outlined. For now, it works to actually do the opposite of what I did with `string.encode("utf-8")`, namely to `string.decode("utf-8")`. I'm not yet sure why this is so.